# Form data is not bound in dynamically added inline formset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I got a question regarding the validation of a dynamically added inline formset in Django. It seems like I am missing something in my implementation.

**Here is my case:**
My project is a team management platform. A team is called Crew and can have several time Schedules. Each Schedule can have several Shifts. Please take a look at my code. At the moment I am able to create a schedule with several, dynamically added forms of the formset for the Shifts, if all fields are valid.

If not, the error for the Shift forms is not displayed and it is filled with the initial data again. It looks like the data of the shift forms is not bound after sending the POST request (because form.is_bound() is false). Moreover the data of Shift forms is not populated again after the POST request. 
What do you think is the cause of this behaviour? Do I have to overwrite the is_valid function? I dont know, because it looks like the function works fine - the data is just not bound correctly to the new forms.

**Views.py**

```
def schedule_add(request, crew_id):
if request.method == "GET":
    form = ScheduleForm()
    ShiftFormSet = formset_factory(ShiftForm)
    return render(request, 'schedule_add2.html', {'form': form, 'formset': ShiftFormSet, 'title':"Zeitplan hinzufügen"})

elif request.method == "POST":
    form = ScheduleForm(request.POST)
    numberOfShifts = int(request.POST['form-TOTAL_FORMS'])
    ShiftFormSet = formset_factory(ShiftForm, extra=numberOfShifts)
    shift_formset = ShiftFormSet(request.POST, prefix='form')
    print(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and shift_formset.is_valid():
        schedule = Schedule()
        schedule.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        schedule.crew = Crew.objects.get(pk=crew_id)
        schedule.location = form.cleaned_data.get('location')
        schedule.subperiod = form.cleaned_data.get('sub_period')
        schedule.save()

        for shift_form in shift_formset:
            if shift_form.is_valid():
                shift = Shift()
                shift.min_user_count = shift_form.cleaned_data.get('min_user_count')
                shift.max_user_count = shift_form.cleaned_data.get('max_user_count')
                shift.start_datetime = shift_form.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
                shift.end_datetime = shift_form.cleaned_data.get('end_time')
                shift.schedule = schedule
                shift.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Zeitplan & Schichten angelegt.')

        return redirect('shifter:crew_view', crew_id=crew_id)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Fehler')

    return render(request, 'schedule_add2.html', {'form': form, 'formset': ShiftFormSet, 'title':"Zeitplan hinzufügen"})
else:
    return redirect('shifter:index')
```

**forms.py**

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='', label="Name")
sub_period = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SubPeriod.objects.all(), empty_label=None, label="Tag")
location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all(), empty_label=None, label="Einsatzort")

class Meta:
    model = Schedule
    fields = ('name', 'sub_period', 'location',)

class ShiftForm(forms.ModelForm):
    min_user_count = forms.IntegerField(required=True, help_text='', label="Min Count", initial=2)
    max_user_count = forms.IntegerField(required=True, help_text='', label="Max Count", initial=4)
    start_time = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, help_text='', label="Shift start", initial=datetime.now)
    end_time = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, help_text='', label="Shift end", initial=datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        model = Shift
        fields = ('start_time','end_time','min_user_count','max_user_count',)
```

**Template**

```
<form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.label_tag }}
                {% if form.is_bound %}
                    {% if field.errors %}
                      {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
                      {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          {{ error }}
                        </div>
                      {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                      {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
                    {% endif %}
                  {% else %}
                    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
                  {% endif %}

                  {% if field.help_text %}
                    <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
                  {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            <h2 class="mt-5">Shifts</h2>
            <table class="table">
                {{ formset.management_form }}

                {% for form in formset.forms %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="formset_row">
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td>
                                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {% if form.is_bound %}
                                    {% if form.errors %}
                                        {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
                                        {% for error in form.errors %}
                                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                              {{ error }}
                                            </div>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% else %}
                                        {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% else %}
                                    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
```

Thanks in advance,
Christopher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning the class, `ShiftFormSet`, to the template (in the third-from-last line of your code) instead of the instance, `shift_formset`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I dont know how I could miss that.